# Issue appending time stamp to a file name when the first hour digit is zero

Tags: file, time, batch-file, timestamp

On a Windows 2008 box the following line works fine if it is after 09:59 and before 00:00.

```
REN "D:\myfile.out" myfile-%DATE:/=%-%TIME::=%%.out
```

However if I execute this before 10:00 I get a syntax error.  It appears to be trying to rename the file with a space rather than a zero. Which causes the error. For example:

```
Myfile-120511- 95343.out -
```

Where I need it to save without errors like this:

```
Myfile-120511-095343.out
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit out the leading space in time as well as editing the colon (:)

```
set FormatedTime=%Time: =0%

REN "D:\myfile.out" myfile-%DATE:/=%-%FormatedTime::=%.out
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, I ended up using:

Comment: set FormattedTime=%Time: =-%  and REN "MyFile.out" MyFile-%DATE:/=%-%FormattedTime::=%%.out  It wouldn't insert the 0 so swapped it for -. Really appreciate your help.  Adam

Answer (score 0):

you must take into account the leading space and the locale date and time format.

I use this code, that (1) temporarily changes the date and time format strings to a well known format, (2) parses the returned %date% and %time% with an appropiate handling of spaces, and (3) places a complete timestamp in the LOGDATETIME variable.

```
:logdatetime
reg copy "HKCU\Control Panel\International" "HKCU\Control Panel\International-Temp" /f >nul
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate /d "yyyy-MM-dd" /f >nul
set LogDate=%date%
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sTimeFormat /d "HH:mm:ss" /f >nul
set LogTime=%Time%
reg copy "HKCU\Control Panel\International-Temp" "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /f >nul
set loghour=%logtime:~0,2%
if "%loghour:~0,1%" == " " set loghour=0%loghour:~1,1%
set logmin=%logtime:~3,2%
if "%logmin:~0,1%" == " " set logmin=0%logmin:~1,1%
set logsec=%logtime:~6,2%
if "%logsec:~0,1%" == " " set logsec=0%logsec:~1,1%
set logyear=%logdate:~0,4%
set logmonth=%logdate:~5,2%
if "%logmonth:~0,1%" == " " set logmonth=0%logmonth:~1,1%
set logday=%logdate:~8,2%
if "%logday:~0,1%" == " " set day=0%day:~1,1%
set logdatetime=%logyear%%logmonth%%logday%%loghour%%logmin%%logsec%
goto :eof
```

to use it in your code, simply invoke it at the beginning of your bat and use the returned LOGDATETIME varialble

```
CALL :logdatetime
...
REN "D:\myfile.out" myfile-%LOGDATETIME%.out
```